# How to write string member of structure to file using fwrite?

Tags: c, file, structure, fwrite

I have a code in c and I am using structure which contains **name** to get user input using scanf() function. whenever i try to write the name in file using **fwrite()** it does not write all the characters I have enter but only few(only four characters). I know the problem is with **sizeof()** of fwrite() function but I cant figure what should be written inside **sizeof()** so I can store the string I get from user. I know it will work if **char name[20]** is used instead of **char *name**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Emp
{
  char *name;
  char *addr;
}*e;

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;

   e=(struct Emp *)malloc(sizeof(struct Emp));
   e->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char )*20);

   fp=fopen("Employee.txt","r+");
   if(fp==NULL)
   {
      fp=fopen("Employee.txt","w+");
      if(fp==NULL)
      {
        printf("cannot open the file");
        exit(1);
      }
    }

      printf("Name of Employee: ");
      scanf("%s",e->name);       
      fwrite(e->name,sizeof(e->name),1,fp);


return 0;
}
```

If I input **name of Employee: chiranjibi**  fwrite()function will only write **chir** in the file. Is there any way to get this code working so i can input any number of characters from user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sizeof(e->name) returns the size of the pointer (typically 4 or 8)

Use `strlen(e->name)` to get the length of the string. Assuming the string in null terminated.

Comment: Thank you very much eyalm. oh! it was that simple.It worked. Another query- I had memory allocated for name using **e->name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char )*20)** why this would not work or can use that memory allocation in any way in fwrite() ?

Comment: you can allocate the exact ammount of chars required fro a string by using strdup() instead of malloc. Do not forget that you need to free that memory...

Answer (score 1):

You can directly give **4** as the second parameter to `fwrite()` call.

```
fwrite(e->name,4,1,fp);
```

Hence, it only write first four character into the file. If you want to change based on user input, declare a variable and fetch from user the number of character to be printed and then pass the variable as the second parameter to this function call.

Comment: Ya I have try that too. I give 100 and 200 as second parameter but this will write unusual character and symbols.